# Oracle DB Query Timestamp with Like and '%'

Tags: sql, database, oracle, timestamp

I want to list all records that whose `TARGET_COMMIT` field days between 10/Nov/2018 and 18/Nov/2018 at around 5.00 AM. I have been using this query:

```
select * from (select * from GGS_ADMIN.GGS_HEARTBEAT_HISTORY  
where DELGROUP='REPDELTA' and TARGET_COMMIT between '10/Nov/2018' 
and '18/Nov/2018') where TARGET_COMMIT like '%/Nov/2018 5:%:%.% AM';
```

Here is one record of my inner query result:

```
SBLPROF,    EDELTA, 11/10/2018 5:56:22.064830 AM,   11/10/2018 
5:56:27.495548 AM,
11/10/2018 5:56:24.731541 AM,   2.666711,               11/10/2018 
5:56:26.305759 AM,  REPDELTA    ,   5.430718,   3,  11/10/2018 
5:56:22.820934 AM,  0,  14441,  0,  14441
```

And here "11/10/2018 5:56:27.495548 AM" is my TARGET_COMMIT field.

If use

```
select * from (select * from GGS_ADMIN.GGS_HEARTBEAT_HISTORY where 
DELGROUP='REPDELTA' and TARGET_COMMIT between '10/Nov/2018'  and 
'18/Nov/2018') where TARGET_COMMIT like '11/10/2018 5:56:27.495548 AM'
```

instead of my previous query it matches and lists the result. Why I can't use the "like" function and "%" for timestamp?

By the way here is my dual result:

```
select sysdate from dual; 

  SYSDATE                 
11/18/2018 04:11:53 PM 
1 row selected.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the datatype of `TARGET_COMMIT`?

Comment: TARGET_COMMIT     TIMESTAMP(6)

Comment: `like` operates on strings, so using `like` on a timestamp means Oracle first has to convert it into a string, which is inefficient and also unpredictable if you don't specify the format, as it will be forced to rely on the session defaults at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `TIMESTAMP` literal and `EXTRACT`.Preferably use `>=` and `<` instead of `BETWEEN` for ranges.

```
SELECT *
FROM ggs_admin.ggs_heartbeat_history
   WHERE delgroup = 'REPDELTA' AND 
   target_commit    >=  TIMESTAMP '2018-11-10 00:00:00' 
AND target_commit   <   TIMESTAMP '2018-11-18 00:00:00' + INTERVAL '1' DAY
AND EXTRACT ( HOUR FROM target_commit) = 5
```

If you want a desired format, you may also use

```
WHERE    
target_commit >=  TO_TIMESTAMP('10/Nov/2018','dd/mon/yyyy')  AND 
target_commit <   TO_TIMESTAMP('18/Nov/2018','dd/mon/yyyy') + INTERVAL '1' DAY
AND EXTRACT ( HOUR FROM target_commit) = 5
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) I have questions for you. I can use the commands "INTERVAL '1' DAY" and "EXTRACT(HOUR FROM target_commit) = 5" because of "target_commit" is "timestamp", right? Also, why using ">=" and "<" preferably instead of "between". Shortly take a look to them, but most says that they are the same. Thanks again :).

Comment: @UmutTEKİN :  Nothing wrong in using `BETWEEN`  if you know how it works. It uses inclusive ranges. So, you have no option but to construct your arguments x and y such that it should satisfy `a >= x && a <= y` when using `BETWEEN`. Using basic operators `>=, <=, <` gives you more flexibility especially when dealing with timestamps. So, I ( and many others here) prefer them.  Regarding your other question, yes. `EXTRACT` and `interval` works on both date and timestamps